# ggsurvplot function in R limiting the x axis

Tags: r

I have been trying for a while now, but I cant figure this out.
I have created a ggsurvplot with:

```
sfit <- survfit(Surv(survalltime, event_crc)~ajcc, data=pheno)
```

I then wanted to change the x-axis from days to years, which also worked with:

```
ggsurvplot(sfit,xscale = "d_y")
```

However, I cant seem to figure out how I can limit it now to 5 years instead of currently 20 years in the x-axis.

I tried this:

```
ggsurvplot(sfit,xscale = "d_y",xlim=c(0,5))
```

But it doesnt work.

### Added plot

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Does specifying the limit in *days* help? E. g. `ggsurvplot(..., xlim = 365 * c(0, 5))`

Comment: Thanks so much. It looks much better now, it seems to be showing till 5 years. However, what happens is that the x-axis doesnt show the year numbers in the axis.  Not sure how I can make it show it? I have added a picture above in my question.

Comment: ah, I think i fixed it with this: ggsurvplot(sfit,xscale = "d_y",xlim = 365 * c(0, 5),break.x.by=365 *(1))